# How to get chain of all child elements from a table without using CTE

Tags: sql-server

For example: A has a child B.
             B has child C and 
             C has child D.
If I search for child elements of A I must get B,C,D.

I must not use CTE

Comment: please provide the code you have done so far

Comment: Why you `must not` use CTE?

Answer (score 1):

for this a new datatype is there like hirerarchyid with this we can get hirarical strecture very easy and better way. but while inserting data itself we have to enter who is under hu like following code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMP](
    [EMPNO] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ENAME] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [JOB] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [MGR] [numeric](4, 0) NULL,
    [HIREDATE] [date] NULL,
    [SAL] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
    [COMM] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
    [DEPTNO] [numeric](2, 0) NULL,
    [hir] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL
)

7839    KING    PRESIDENT   NULL    1981-11-17  5000.00 NULL    10  /
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 7839    1981-01-05  2850.00 NULL    30  /1/
7782    CLARK   MANAGER 7839    1981-09-06  2450.00 NULL    10  /1/1/
7566    JONES   MANAGER 7839    1981-02-04  2975.00 NULL    20  /2/
```

here / is root node 
and /1/1/ is one under one like that it follows
here there is many methode gothrough following link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37171/HierarchyID-Data-Type-in-SQL-Server